# Node Typescript: JSON undefined when using bracket notation

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, aws-lambda

I have a node project with typescript and I'm trying to read the right url from a json object.
However when using square bracket notation I get undefined.

```
{
    "env":"dev",
    "dev":{
        "url": "url1"
    },
    "aws":{
        "url": "url2"
    }
}
```

For some reason this does not work:

```
const url = config[config.env].url;
```

The code below accomplishes what I need, but it is not as flexible as the above and I want to understand why it does not work the other way.

```
const cenv:string = config.env;
    let url=null;
    if( cenv === "dev")
        url = config["dev"].url;
    else
        url = config["aws"].url;
```

This is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The json is imported to the project like so:

```
import * as config from './config.json';
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is because Typescript infers the value for `env` to be of type `string`, which means it can be any string value. You can see this when you inspect `typeof config`:

[image]

Because Typescript thinks that `env` can be any string value, it throws an error. What would happen for example if you compiled this code, but then changed the `env` value to be "foobar"? The code would throw, and Typescript guards you from this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating `config` folder

```
config/
  settings.dev.json
  settings.prod.json
  index.js

// index.js
module.exports = function(){
    switch(process.env.NODE_ENV){
        case 'development':
            return require('./settings.dev.json');

        case 'production':
            return require('./settings.prod.json');

        default:
            return {error or other settings};
    }
};
```

If you want to use approach you can do it this way:

```
enum Enivornment {
  Dev = "dev",
  Aws = "aws"
}

type Config = {
  "env": Enivornment,
} & {
  [key in Enivornment]: ConfigItem
}

// this will help you have all environments in sync
type ConfigItem = {
  "url": string
} 

const config: Config = {
    "env": Enivornment.Dev,
    [Enivornment.Dev]: {
        "url": "url1"
    },
    [Enivornment.Aws]:{
        "url": "url2"
    }
}
```

You can test it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAoiCWA3A9gJxBUAXKBvAUFFACLCJQC8UARACZnUA0hUAggO4DOlNAhl9XwBffPiwBPAA7AoAYWQgAZvADmPAkWqhE1AFywEKdJhBZmQqADI8LANoBrYOKjwQBpGgzYAuvvlLVAEksYAhhUQB6CKgsAAt4bnZ4ABtkqFjgZMkocWQwdN5EGV5UqG14VAUTLG5XKE5xEABjMSkZf2UVYND1FmowVGS9eqxUVxVhKFEmhU4cGYCVPwVO3qJNbWG4D2NsADpSRGZ1qFttoy9TA7JfGxOT-sHhx+SARkEToWP1s8NPar2HE4vg0900AyG+heACYPusRCJ8AtOrZkao9tpvHsIUA).